# Tkinter textvariable not updated with MatplotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, label

Can anyone help me here? The textvariable is not being updated when I add the line:

```
f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))
```

If I comment the line above, then I see the textvariable being updated in the Label, but as soon as I uncomment the line, the Label is not updated anymore.
Can anyone help me, please?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.artist as artists
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation

f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))

class make_window():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.title("Test")
        self.win.state("zoomed")

        Frame = ttk.Frame(self.win)
        Frame.pack()

        labelVar = StringVar()
        labelVar.set("Hi")
        self.LabelUpdate = Label(Frame, textvariable = labelVar)
        self.LabelUpdate.pack()


#################################################################################

window = make_window()
window.win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not updated"? When I run the code, I see [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfQyh.png). In how far is this not what you want?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest On my side I do not get that window. The label does not show up in my screen.

Comment: I see one major problem here. `f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))`. For whatever reason this line is stopping tkinter from allowing the label to work. I find this very odd.

Comment: Well, but it does this *only in your case*. So you may want to make your case more reproducible for others, by stating your system, versions in use, the way you run the code etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it appears they are using "Figure"  wrong here. They are doing `f = plt.figure(figsize=(20,9))` but from what I have been reading they should be doing `f = Figure(figsize=(20,9))`. Making that change has allowed the label to work as it should.

Comment: It totally depends on what you want to do. If you want a pyplot figure, use `plt.figure()`, if you want your figure embedded inside the tk window, use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` (and set this figure to a `FigureCanvasTkAgg` afterwards). Both concepts should work in principle.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest interesting. When I copy the OP's code the `self.LabelUpdate` fails to show text. It does pack to the window but without the assigned StringVar text. When I comment out `f` the label works as expected.

Comment: I can only help more here if I know more about your/the OP's system.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest well I am using Python 3.6.2 on windows 7. Honestly I do not see how `f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))` should affect the tkinter label that is later in the code. I find it very odd that it is blocking the text from displaying in the code but everything else is working as expected.

Comment: Ok, so the main point is that you are probably using the `TkAgg` backend. So there will be a pyplot figure with tk created, as well as the `self.win` tk instance. They seem to collide. A solution would hence be to use a different backend (`matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")`) for the pyplot part. Of course the optimal solution would indeed depend on what the whole purpose of this code is (because currently just creating a figure, does not make much sense anyways.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I came to the same conclusions however I think that the TkAgg back end is only an issue when the `plt.figure` is called before `self.win`. The code works as intended once you move `f` past `self.win` and my guess is that matplotlib is recognizing the active tk instance and using that instead of creating its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed a few issues that you need to address.

First the way you are importing (`from tkinter import *`) is going to cause problems and in fact here in this case you make the kind of mistake this import is known for. Later in your code you do `Frame = ttk.Frame()` and this one line is actually overriding the `Frame` import from `from tkinter import *`. Do not name your variables the same as built in methods. In order to prevent this kind of mistake you can simply do `import tkinter as tk` and always use the `tk.` prefix to prevent any overriding in your code.

Next I noticed your Label does pack to the screen but does not show any text oddly enough but when I comment out `f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))` the Label starts to work as expected.

So there is some odd interaction here with matplotlib and this label.

When I change `f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))` to `f = Figure(figsize=(20,9))` the label also works again.

If `Figure()` is not exactly what you are trying to use here then please add some more context to your code as to what you are expecting to do with `f`.

Update:

I did also notice that when you move `f` to be after `self.win = tk.Tk()` the code works fine. My only guess as to why this is happening is possible how matplotlib does have its own tkinter code in it. So if you try to create a `plt.figure` before you create your tkinter instance then I imaging in the back end a tkinter instance is being ran by matplotlib and this is what is causing the odd behavior. I could be wrong but I cannot think of anything else. Maybe the Tkinter master Bryan Oakley can enlighten us as to what is causing this :D

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.artist as artists
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation


class make_window():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        # moving the line to here should at least allow your code to work.
        f = plt.figure(0, figsize=(20,9))
        self.win.title("Test")
        self.win.state("zoomed")

        frame = ttk.Frame(self.win)
        frame.pack()

        labelVar = tk.StringVar()
        labelVar.set("Hi")
        self.LabelUpdate = tk.Label(frame, textvariable = labelVar)
        self.LabelUpdate.pack()


window = make_window()
window.win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike - SMT. This works indeed. Despite I can't understand why, your solution solved my problem!