# python 3 Tkinter Checkbutton value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hey guys i´m new to tkinter and i´m testing stuff out.
In this code i´m getting the error "'Graphicaluserinterface' object has no attribute 'var'" which i don´t understand, since i have it in my **init** method.
My Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Graphicaluserinterface(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.startbuttonfunktion()
        self.checkbutton1
        self.var=IntVar()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.programmstart = tk.Button(self, text = "Programmstart")
        self.programmstart.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.programmstart["command"]=self.startbuttonfunktion

        self.programmschliessen = tk.Button(self, text ="Exit Programm",command=root.destroy)
        self.programmschliessen.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Sensoren1",variable=self.var,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
        self.checkbutton1.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def startbuttonfunktion(self):
        if self.var.get()==1:
            print("Der Checkbutton wurde geklickt")
        else:
            print("Der Checkbutton wurde NICHT geklickt")



root = tk.Tk()        
app = Graphicaluserinterface(master=root)
app.master.title("TestProgramm")
app.master.maxsize(1200,600)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is order of operation. You are only creating the `self.var` IntVar after you run your other methods. So when those methods try to access `self.var` they cannot because it has not been created yet.

Move `self.var=IntVar()` Above `self.create_widgets()`.

That said you need to also change `IntVar()` to `tk.IntVar()` as you have shown you are doing `import tkinter as tk` and thus all tkinter widgets will need a `tk.` prefix.

Make those 2 changes and you code will work fine.

Comment: ah wow thank you it works now :) 
I think i understand why the order of operation is necessary, but can you elaborate on why i need to change it to tk.IntVar() ?

Comment: @James `IntVar()` is a tkinter method. Because you are importing tkinter as `tk` all tkinter methods required the `tk.` prefix to call them. This rule applies to all imported libraries. The only time you can do just `IntVar()` is if you import the method directly with either `from tkinter import *` to import all content of tkinter or `from tkinter import IntVar` to import just IntVar directly.

Comment: ah ok i understand now, the thing is i used "import tkinter as tk" from another code sample i found on the internet because "from tkinter import *" didn´t work with my code, i didn´t understand why because syntax wise the code shouldn´t change should it?

Comment: @James `from tkinter import *` will work if you remove all the `tk.` prefixes from your code first. That said it is best to use `import tkinter as tk` to prevent accidentally overriding built in methods.

Comment: would you also recommend "import tkinter as tk" when i want to implement this class into other code i´m working on?

Comment: @James I use `import tkinter as tk` for everything I do with tkinter. It is just better for maintainability and avoiding overrides.

Comment: _"IntVar() is a tkinter method. "_ is not quite correct. `IntVar` is a class, not a method.

Comment: @BryanOakley true. I should be more clear with my statement on that. I have a bad habit of calling everything imported from a library a method. That said I would really love to know your thoughts on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062637/tkinter-textvariable-not-updated-with-matplotlib). There is some interesting behavior with matplotlib and a label and I would like to know if my idea was accurate or not.

Comment: ok i will use "import tkinter as tk" then from now on, thank you very much for your help i learned alot!

Comment: @James glad to help. :D. Be sure to select the check mark next to the answer if it has solved your problem. This shows your issue is resolved.

Comment: @Mike-SMT by the way i just realized that my code will work with both "import tkinter as tk" and "from tkinter import *" no matter if i delete the tk. prefixes which is quite odd

Comment: @James well likely not. Did you remove `import tkinter as tk` when you added `from tkinter import *`? If you have both imports in there then yes the code will still work but at that point it is overkill. Try just `from tkinter import *` and let me know how that works for you.

Comment: no i removed import tkinter as tk  of course, thats why it´s irretating me.

Comment: sorry i edited my comment, because i tried it both with removing the prefixes and not removing them, and either way it worked with both import commands separately

Comment: @James `tk.Button`, `tk.Checkbutton` and `tk.Tk` should fail if you removed `import tkinter as tk`. These will not work with `from tkinter import *`. Unless you remove the `tk.` prefix from all of the widgets.

Comment: yes but still my code is working (i´m using jupyter notebook btw). either way it doesn´t matter i´m going with "import tkinter as tk" now and i´ll put the prefix anyways to reduce further syntax errors.

Comment: @James hum. Jupiter Notebook must be auto importing tkinter then. Maybe some feature of JN. In any case in raw python it would not work so Just keep that in mind for the future. I will take a look at JN to see what its all about.